# How to run zookeeper.sh file in windows

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, sh, apache-zookeeper

I am following [this](https://medium.com/egen/securing-kafka-cluster-using-sasl-acl-and-ssl-dec15b439f9d) tutorial where i have to run this command in order to start the zookeeper server.

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

But the problem is this command is not working properly. I found that .sh file is bash file that required cygwin. I have installed it and then run command like this

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

But it is showing:

[image]

I can confirm that in bin directory the file is exsits. what i am doing wrong?

Here is my directory snapshot from where i running the command:
[image]

Note: I have successfully tested `bin/windows` zookeeper bat file but i want to run it through .sh file as [the kafka security tutorial](https://medium.com/egen/securing-kafka-cluster-using-sasl-acl-and-ssl-dec15b439f9d) which i am following using this.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, I conclude that you are using Cygwin. So, please add the *cygwin* tag to your question.

As you can see from the error message, the command `dirname` is not found by bash, so assuming that your Cygwin installation is not broken, I assume that the PATH is not set correctly; in your setup, dirname.exe should be in C:/cygwin64/bin (please verify this).

Your usage of bash.exe is a bit unusual in that you run it directly from a Windows cmd prompt. The more common way would be to use it from the 'Cygwin Terminal', which you get created a Windows-link to, when installing Cygwin, or to use another suitable Terminal program; I'm using for instance mintty for this task (also available via the Cygwin installer).

Having said this, it **is** possible to run bash.exe in the way you are doing it, but you then have to ensure, that at least the PATH is set up correctly. One possibility to do this, is to add C:\cygwin64\bin to your Windows PATH, but this has the drawback, that some commands have the same name in the Windows world and in Cygwin, though they serve a completely different purpose, and this will bite you sooner or later. Another problem is that at some point, you will rely on other bash specific setups besides the PATH.

A better way to accomplish your goal is IMO to ensure, that the system wide bash-initialization files are sourced by bash. If I have to run the script from a Windows cmd prompt, I would run it by

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login YOURSCRIPT
```

This will read the file (in your setup)  `C:\cygwin64\etc\profile` before running YOURSCRIPT, so you can check, that the PATH is correctly set there, by looking at this file. In a default installation, this should be the case.

After having read this file, it will try to read the file `.bash_profile` in your Cygwin HOME directory, so if you need additional settings for your (non-interactive) bash-scripts, create this file and put your settings there.

Comment: No, as you see: `bash` is executed. `dirname` is not found. You have to read the error messages carefully.

Comment: I have updated my directory strucuture in the question. Please see the picture in question. From that location i am running this C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe  ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties

Comment: I don't see what your directory structure has to do with your issue. You can layout your directories as you please. Just follow the advice in my answer!

Comment: run the command from the "Cygwin Terminal". It will avoid the need to run bash from CMD